# Python Selenium get nth parent and nth child

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

i am looking for a solution to get the second parent (div) of a known element and then get a child element with sub-childrens in selenium with python.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="p1">
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <span class="target">b_Kunden</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <div class="p4">
                <div class="p5">
                    <div class="p6">
                        <button type="button" class="b1">button i want to click</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="p1">
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <span class="target">different</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <div class="p4">
                <div class="p5">
                    <div class="p6">
                        <button>some button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="p1">
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <span class="target">different</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">...</div>
    <div class="p2">
        <div class="p3">
            <div class="p4">
                <div class="p5">
                    <div class="p6">
                        <button>some button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the element I am looking for with xpath and checking for a specific text ("b_Kunden")(working fine):

```
temp = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'b_Kunden')]")[0]
```

** I cannot access it trough simple className etc. This is just
dummy HTML in environment I need to go up to p1 class from where span text is "b_Kunden" and then down to child element p6 to click the button inside it **

The reason for this is I need to press exactly the button of the section where the span text is b_Kunden. Because the amount of the sections is variable I cannot count and access them trough example: [1] operator for classes. I need to find the term "b_Kunden" and press the relate button in the p1 section to it.

I would be glad if someone could help me out on how to solve this issue.

Best regards,
Liam

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you (assuming that the 2nd parent you referred to is going backwards in heirarchy (higher up the DOM):

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'b_Kunden')][1]//parent::div//parent::div")
```

UPDATE (code per the comment and html block provided by @Liam)

```
//*[text()='b_Kunden']//ancestor::div//button
```

Here is the HTML with DOM highlighted to the button. I hope this is what you are looking for.

[HTML DOM highlighted snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiQzh.png)

Comment: Hey Anand, thanks for the quick answer. I tried to implement this but I can't figure to how the code would look like in my example without getting errors..

Comment: sorry, I modified my code. Please check. Also, as @undetectedselenium pointed out, please post your HTML code in code format and not snapshot. It is all the better if you could post the website url if you can as it would help to inspect and test direclty on the website DOM

Comment: I quickly wrote a html file because the original site is protected with login infos. If you watch source code you can see the structure. I need to acess this button trough finding the text "b_Kunden" first then move up to the wrapping div and access down to the children where the button is.(in this case I could easily access by class name but in real environment not so I need to do it like this way)  https://wee-ti.de/main.html

Comment: @Liam Thanks for posting such a nice code. I appended an update to my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Problem here is in my real environment there are more divs above the p1 class and more buttons in tota in higher hirachyl. So In my real environment this code goes up to the (in hierarchy) highest button. and not to the button I want to target. So I guess I need to limit the ancestor that it does not expand over the p1 class

Comment: If `ancestor` goes way up than you require, you can use `parent` until you get to the desired parent and then traverse down to the button from there, like in my first example:

`browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'b_Kunden')][1]//parent::div//parent::div//button")`

something like this

Comment: Ah thanks you helped me a lot. Your screen was useful since I did not know that I could search for paths directly in the html inspector. Thank you :)